# Is there a turn-based strategy game that allows building AI from scratch?

Tags: ai

I'm very interested in programming Artificial Intelligence for a turn-based game as a project. However, I'm looking for a (somewhat modern) game and can't really find one i'm interested in.

Particularly, i'm looking at the Civilization francise. I'd love to be able to program the AI of Civilization V for instance. However, as of now, you can only slightly modify the settings of the AI: http://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/artificial-unintelligence.536193/.

Is there any game, which has been released at least in the  last 10 years, that allows programming of the AI to (nearly) ground level?

Comment: Crusader Kings 2 might be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Not within 10 years, but Warcraft 3 had the ability to completely edit the AI script.

Comment: I wanted to also elaborate that most, if not all, implementations of AI take the form of conditional logic, which are then weighted in spectrums of importance. The higher valued decision is chosen and, if applicable, the others are prioritized for later execution.

Comment: Unfortunately not only is this question asking for a list of things, it's essentially asking for a game recommendation and not really anything to do with game development. You might want to try [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).